# Excel function to aggregate (mean) timely values (each second) to intervals of minutes / hours etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a bit lost trying to find a solution similar to the aggregate function of R. Pivot-tables or the grouping function of Excel do not apply.

The data is a series of measurements taken almost each second for one day. 
The table has colums for date, time and corresponding measurement values.

At best the values should be grouped for each minute/hour. Finally resulting in a more compact table with the time-stamp reduced to minutes and a mean-value as aggregate of the measurement-values.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you'd like to get a mean of all values with the same minute value, regardless of seconds?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to accumulate all of the (up to 60) seconds-values of the same minute within a mean value and display the corresponding timestamp of hour&minute aside.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. First method, make a second sheet called Proc or other name you like. In it has 60 columns or whatever you prefer. There is a formula in each cell that extracts the values from the raw data sheet.  You can make the formula use a term that allows switching from seconds, minutes, hours.  For hours some columns will be zero.  Then make a summary sheet that pulls from the second sheet.

Comment: Make  additional columns to the right of the data. One for second the other for minute, maybe hour  or day if needed.  Extract the time from the data to fill cells. Then could use sumifs, countifs, etc. where they refer in part to the extracted time.

Comment: The problem is, that the time-stamp is not static! Sometimes I have 50 values each minute and sometimes 60. So I can not simply use a function saying take the mean of 60 values, then the next 60 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

We'll want to put the data into a new table with the correct summation. So, no change to the existing data, we'll create a new table, say on a new worksheet, with the times we're interested in:

```
Time | Mean Value
12:00|
12:01|
12:02|
12:03|
```

... etc. You can enter the first two times then use the fill handle in the lower-right of the cell highlight to copy them down, incrementing by one minute at each step.

In the Mean Value column, we'll use an `AVERAGEIFS` function to average values by criteria. The formula will be something like:
`=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$361,$A$2:$A$361,">=" & $D2,$A$2:$A$361, "<" & $D3)`

...where B2:B361 is the range containing your values, A2:A361 is the range containing the times, D2 is the cell containing a start time (this would be 12:00 in the table above), and D3 is a cell containing the next timestamp (12:01 in the table). This will average all values where the timestamp is greater than or equal to each minute bucket, but less than the next minute.

You can use a similar structure to collapse minutes to hours.

Note that this formula will give a #DIV/0! error if there are no values that match the time period. You can fix that by including the entire formula in an `IFERROR` function, if needed.

Comment: Many Thanks! This was getting me somewhere. But somehow I have to find out where I went wrong. I'm getting the #DIV/0! error, even though I can't locate where that originates. My main worksheet is called Table1 and contains Date | Time | Value - The second worksheet for mean value calculation (Table2) contains only Time | Mean. The function for the first value is '=AVERAGEIFS($Table1.$C$2:$C$42598,$Table1.$B$2:$B$42598,">="&$A2,$Tabelle1.$B$2:$B$42598,"<"&$A3)' Seems alright to me but perhaps I have to start off more basic to understand the function correctly.